# Allocating colours to groups in stacked bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make stacked bar charts for vegetation survey data. Not every plot has the same vegetation and I want each type of vegetation to be allocated its own colour however I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(pcm, aes(x = sample, fill = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  xlab("Plot") + ylab("% Abundance") + 
  labs(fill = "Vegetation Type")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", 
                    labels = c("C.vulgaris", "E.tetralix", "V.myrtillus", 
                               "E.angustifolium", "E.vaginatum", "C.flexuosus", 
                               "H.jutlandicum", "P.strictum", "Bare"))
```

This works fine but as soon as I try something like this....

```
ggplot(pcm, aes(x = sample, fill = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  xlab("Plot") + ylab("% Abundance") + labs(fill = "Vegetation Type")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Cal_vul" = "#ff0000", "Vac_myr" = "#ff8080", 
                               "Eri_ang" = "#ff00ff", "Eri_vag" ="##ffccff", 
                               "Hyp_jut" = "#4000ff", "Pol_spp" = "#c6b3ff", 
                               "Bare" = "#0080ff", "Bsh/dd" = "#b3d9ff" ), 
                    name = "Vegetation Type", 
                    labels = c("C.vulgaris", "V.myrtillus", "E.angustifolium", 
                               "E.vaginatum", "H.jutlandicum", "P.strictum", 
                               "Brash", "Brash"))
```

all colours go from my plot and the vegetation groups are removed from my legend.

Comment: I can't say why your colors are dissappearing without a reproducible example; you'll need to provide some (real or fake) data that reproduces your problem.